# Determine if the system is linear, time invariant

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, continuous-signals, linear-systems

I have a system described by the following impulse response:

$h(t,τ) = g(t-2τ)$

Where $g(t) = e^{-at}u(t)$

I have to determine if the system is

- linear
- time invariant
- causal

Then I have to determine the response to the signal

$x(t) = rect(\frac{t+1}{2})$

I asked recently something quite similar, if it was possible to determine the linearity of a system from the impulse response

But in this case it is asked to prove and justify the answer, and I don't know how to proceed (anyways the are more things known in this problem)

**Time-Invariant**

For the system to be time invariant or not I thought it is not time invariant because you can't express $h(t, τ)$ as a function of $(t - τ)$

$h(t, τ) = e^{-a(t-2τ)}u(t-2τ)$

And we have $t-2τ$ instead of $t-τ$

**Linearity**

In this case I don't think the answer to the problem would be that it is linear otherwise having the impulse response wouldn't be too useful, just because it is asked to prove the system to be linear or not, but again, I don't know

I thought I could see g(t) as something similar to the y(t), but in this case it fails to be linear because of the presence of the exponential

I think the system should be linear because otherwise I wouldn't know how to find the response to the input $x(t)$

Maybe I'm just not seeing something obvious and the problem is far easier than I thought

I didn't know if I had to open a new post or write this question on the other one and asking for clarification, sorry if this was not the appropriate way

Comment: The impulse response of a linear system is basically arbitrary. There's no way to tell if a system is linear just by knowing how it responds to an impulse.

Comment: Here's an example with discrete-time systems to make the math easier. Consider the systems `y1[n] = x[n]` and `y2[n] = (x[n])^2`. Their impulse response is identical, but one is linear and the other is not.

Comment: In continuous-time: $y_1(t) = x(t)$ and $y_2(t) = \delta(t)$ have the same impulse response.

Comment: Thanks, this does make a lot of sense but then I can't understand what is the exercise asking, you can't go on and you can't determine anything, so I don't get how it could be possible to proceed.
I'm gonna ask the proposal of this exercise how it was inteded to be resolved, and then post the "solution" here to get a larger overview of the problem, to understand if the exercise itself is somehow an error or otherwise.

Comment: At the end it was to suppose the system was linear, as a consequence for having the impulse response, and then to prove the lineary with the convolution...
For anyone seeing the post, there's no other way to do it (and to be honest proving something that is supposed doesn't make to me a lot of sense, I don't know where the exercise aimed at)
I don't think anyone else is gonna receive a similar exercise